# Find the sum of $2^{n-1}$ of the products obtained in choosing $[n-1]$ elements in separate cards..

Tags: combinatorics, recursion

We write each element of [$n-1]$  on a separate card, then randomly select any number of cards, and take the product of the numbers of written on them. Then we do this for all $2^{n-1}$ possible subsets of the set of $n-1$ cards. (The empty product is taken to be $1$) . Finallly, we take the sum of the $2^{n-1}$ products obtained. What is the sum?
give a combinatorial answer.

attempt: Let $[n-1]= {\{1,2,....,n-1}\}$. Let $S(n)$ the sum of $n$ terms.
Then if we pick randomly any number of cards, then we assume that the card can have a number or not, and so there are two options, either yes, or no. then we can do this for all $2^{n-1}$ possible subsets.

If we choose 1 element, the element would have its sum as either zero or that number. For example if we say $1 \leq a \leq n-1 $
So if $a$ is just one element, then $a$ has to options 
So S(1) = 0 or S(1) = a

For two numbers, say  $b,d$ then 
$S(2) = 0 $ or $S(2) = b+d$.

So if we take three cards, for example, and get A, 3s, and 2s, then their product will be 1 because we would have empty product.

or its sum.

I am not sure how to define a sum, could someone please give me an example or some feedback? I don't know how to define a formula , I was thinking a recursive formula to give the sum of the $2^{n-1}$ products obtained.
I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: For $n=4$, you get the sum of the products:

$$1 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 1\cdot 2 + 1\cdot 3+2\cdot 3 + 1\cdot 2\cdot 3$$

Comment: is the first $1$ suppose to be if it's empty the product ? Why do you have $1+1$ at the beginning? I am confuse,don't we just have to take the sum of their products? why do we add $1+1+2+3$?

Comment: the subset with no element has product $1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use induction,the empty product is equal to $1$.  Let $F_n$ be the desired number.

We have $F_2=1+1$.

For $n\geq 3$ notice that the sum of the product over all the subsets that dont contain $n-1$ is $F_{n-1}$ and the sum of the products over all subsets that do contain $n-1$ is $(n-1)F_{n-1}$ so we get $F_n=nF_{n-1}$

and so we clearly have $F_n=n!$

Comment: the subsets of the set $\{1\}$ are the empty set and $\{1\}$, each of these has product $1$.

Comment: So we have $F_2$ means when just the element $1$ is selected and it has product $1$, and the other $1$ refers to when no item is selected?

Comment: Yes, and in general $F_n$ is the sum of all the products.

Comment: you found $F_n $ by adding $(n-1)F_{n-1}$ and by adding the terms in $F_{n-1}$ multiplied by $n$ and adding these result to $(n+1)F(n-1)$?

Comment: $F_n=F_{n-1}+(n-1)F_{n-1}$

Comment: yes that really helps. Thanks